# Interpolation texture of 2 diff size mesh python

Tags: python, arrays, interpolation, mesh, resampling

I have a mesh1 with N1(number of points) points are of shape (x y z) and tex1 array of 1 dim with N1 values either (0 or1)

I have a mesh2 with N2 points, shape of (x y z) but i don't have tex2

Both meshes have the same shape but different number of point that constitute the mesh N1 > N2

I want to make the tex2 for mesh2 with N2 points based on the tex1 of mesh1

Example :

mesh1 : points : [[1,1,1],[1,2,2],[3,2,1]], tex1[0,0,1]

mesh2 : points : [[1,2,1],[1,3,2]], tex2 [?,?]

I tried interpolation, but it requires to have the same length, and I don't know how to make the relation on the texture arrays

Any help is appreciated . Thanks in advance